# Implementing Reddit type voting in Flask with secondary table containing User, Post, Vote Models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement Reddit type app with voting feature upvote, downvote for each posts. I'm trying to extend this Many-To-Many Relationship [example](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) from `flask-sqlachemy` documentation page.

```
vote_list = db.Table("vote_list",
       db.Column("vote", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("vote.id"), primary_key=True),
       db.Column("user", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
       db.Column("post", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    vote_list = db.relationship('Vote', secondary=vote_list, backref='user_votes')

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)    
    vote_list = db.relationship('Vote', secondary=vote_list, backref='post_votes')

    def add_vote(self, tag):
        if vote not in self.vote_list:
            self.vote_list.append(vote)
            return True
        return False

class Vote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)  # values up, down, unvote
```

I was wondering, how can add correctly a vote to post using `add_vote` method in `Post` class or directly in `vote` route.

```
@app.route("/vote/<int:user_id>/<int:post_id>/<string:action>", methods=['POST'])
def vote(user_id, post_id, action):
    if current_user.is_authenticated and action == 'up':
        if not Vote.query.filter_by(name='upvote').first():
            db.session.add(Vote(name='upvote'))
            post.add_vote(Vote.query.filter_by(name='upvote').first())
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a separate table for types of votes (effectively it will only ever have 3 rows, no?) is definitely overkill. I would just extend your `Vote` model to be an association object between a user and a post, with the additional `upvote` (boolean) column to track whether it's an upvote (True) or a downvote (False).

```py
class Vote(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    user = db.relationship("User", backref=db.backref("votes", cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True)
    post = db.relationship("Post", backref=db.backref("votes", cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    upvote = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
```

Then you can just add a vote by creating a new `Vote` object and adding it to the db:

```py
@app.route("/vote/<int:user_id>/<int:post_id>/<string:action>", methods=['POST'])
def vote(user_id, post_id, action):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        upvote = action == 'upvote'
        vote = Vote(user_id=user_id, post_id=post_id, upvote=upvote)
        db.session.add(vote)
        db.session.commit()
```

Also you should probably be getting the `user_id` from your `current_user` object rather than including it in the endpoint, so that users can only vote for themselves. Otherwise I could just send POST requests with random user IDs.

If it were me, I would probably have my endpoint be more like:

```py
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/vote/<int:upvote_int>", methods=['POST'])
def vote(post_id, upvote_int):
    upvote = bool(upvote_int)
    ...
```

and pass `0` for downvote and `1` for upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer of [ascnebs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8662954/acnebs), here working code for me. First of all making some changes in models (adding backrefs to User and Post):

```
class PostVote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('user_post_votes'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    post = db.relationship('Post', backref=db.backref('all_post_votes'))
    upvote = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.upvote == True:
            vote = 'Up'
        else:
            vote = 'Down'
        return '<Vote - {}, from {} for {}>'.format(vote, self.user.username, self.post.header)

class Post(db.Model)
    ...
    post_votes = db.relationship('PostVote', backref='post_votes', lazy='dynamic')


class User(db.Model)
    ...
    user_post_vote = db.relationship('PostVote', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

here my route:

```
@bp.route('/_post_vote/<post_id>/<action_vote>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def _post_vote(post_id, action_vote):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id = post_id).first_or_404()
    vote = PostVote.query.filter_by(
        user = current_user,
        post = post).first()
    if vote:
        if vote.upvote != bool(int(action_vote)):
            vote.upvote = bool(int(action_vote))
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('main._post', post_id = post.id))
        else:
            flash('You already vote for this post')
            return redirect(url_for('main._post', post_id = post.id))

    vote = PostVote(user = current_user, post = post, upvote = bool(int(action_vote)))
    db.session.add(vote)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Thx for voting')
    return redirect(url_for('main._post', post_id = post.id))
```

And in my template i use:

```
<strong class="font-weight-bold mt-0">
    <a href="{{ url_for('main._post_vote', post_id = post.id, action_vote = 1) }}">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up mr-2"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('main._post_vote', post_id = post.id, action_vote = 0) }}">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down ml-2"></i>
    </a>
</strong>
```